# How do I copy the IP results of a ping command to the hosts file?

Tags: windows, hosts

Basically, I am confused as how to do this.

I need a script that pings a site, then copies the IP address of said site to the hosts file. How do I do this automatically? e.g I input www.wikihow.com, then it copies 151.101.28.68 to the hosts file?

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you on linux, unix, windows, solaris, or ....?

Comment: Concerned that this may be a bad idea.  The DNS system is intended to hold the lookup from a distinguished name to an ip address.  These can change over time, and using the host file for a dns system is dangerous (result in machine not able to connect properly to the internet)

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný Windows sorry. have edited question